# UWP Store and Load video encoding properties in settings

Tags: c#, uwp

I can store a setting for a selected camera device on a drop-down list using:

```
nSelectedCam = videodevicelistbox.SelectedIndex;
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["camSetting"] = nSelectedCam;
```

then retrieve with:

```
Object camsetvalue = localSettings.Values["camSetting"];
nSelectedCam = Convert.ToInt32(camsetvalue);
```

But I can't work out how to do the same for a camera device setting(preview), in this case, the resolution, frame rate and aspect ratio. These encoding properties are selectable from a single selection in a ComboBox:

```
var encodingProperties = (selectedItem.Tag as StreamResolution).EncodingProperties;
await _previewer.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, encodingProperties);
```

Can anyone recommend the simplest way to store and retrieve the encoding properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/set-media-encoding-properties#a-media-encoding-properties-helper-class) to expose properties for the resolution, frame rate and aspect ratio, ect. In addition, it is not supported to store the entire encoding properties in LocalSettings, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#settings) to check which data types it supports. If you want to store and retrieve the encoding properties, you might try to use [ApplicationDataCompositeValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-19041) class to store these properties one by one and then store the composite setting into localsetting or you could convert it as json string and then store it in the localsetting.

Comment: update on this, I ended up saving the index number of the item selected in the combobox as nSelectedIndex and reload after previewing with combobox.SelectedIndex = nSelectedIndex
Took me way too long to figure that out, but seems to be working so far.